# Flutter: how to play animation with Provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-provider

I use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to manage state in my Flutter demo.

I want to animate my widget but it seems that AnimateController needs a sync parameter that comes from the state of a stateful widget.

As far as I know, Provider is not recommended to use with a stateful widget.

Can I manage the AnimationController with Provider?

Or must use both Provider and stateful widget?

Comment: Animations belong to the UI, not the state. You need to provide a Ticker to Animation controller. You can use SingleTickerProviderStateMixin to avoid creating it manually. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin-mixin.html

Comment: @RicardoMarkiewicz what if I want to trigger an animation from a different child of same parent

Comment: @RicardoMarkiewicz but we all agree that state defines UI? I think Javan wants to know how to make nice animations upon state change when the widget tree gets destroyed. Provider is easy to handle but the instant switch of widgets on state change is strange. How do you tackle that? Say you push login, app starts to login, then switches to downloading profile, downloading this and that and at the end revel the final logged in interface?

Comment: Your animation controller should be in the UI part, not in the state class because animations are not part of your application state (e.g. are your use logged in?) but part of the UI transient state (state get lost when you leave that screen). You need to use boh Provider and a StatefulWidget, you can use AnimatedWidget, you can use FlutterHooks, but never manage your animations from your state/mode classes.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I manage the AnimationController with Provider?
>
> Or must use both Provider and stateful widget?

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but here is how I do this :

I use [didUpdateWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) in a Stateful widget. I pass the value from the provider to the parent and trigger the animation in the `didUpdateWidget` method defined in the child. `didUpdateWidget` being triggered itself when I notify listeners from a change in the Provider.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String valueFromProvider;

  MyWidget({this.valueFromProvider});

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(MyWidget oldWidget) {
    // TODO: implement didUpdateWidget
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    if (oldWidget.valueFromProvider == "whatever you want" &&
        widget.valueFromProvider == "what you want that changed") {
      // trigger animations methods here
    }
  }

  // here all the animations methods,dispose method, etc. 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create **AnimationController** in the **StatelessWidget** you must pass **TickerProviderStateMixin** in the Constructor of your StatelessWidget, look at my sample code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(TestyApp());
}

class TestyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestyAppState createState() => _TestyAppState();
}

class _TestyAppState extends State<TestyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TestAnimationInStatelessWidget(
        tickerProviderStateMixin: this,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestAnimationInStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final TickerProviderStateMixin tickerProviderStateMixin;

  const TestAnimationInStatelessWidget(
      {Key key, @required this.tickerProviderStateMixin})
      : assert(tickerProviderStateMixin != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var _animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: tickerProviderStateMixin, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));

    var _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 2).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeInOut));

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            RotationTransition(
              turns: _animation,
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _animationController.reset();
                _animationController.forward();
              },
              child: Text("Start Animation"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: in your example you are using a stateful widget.

Answer (score 1):

I made a work-around overriding the didChangeDependencies method, which fires off AnimationController.forward when prompted.

I got the idea from this stackoverflow thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59400368/how-to-do-something-if-changenotifier-notifies-with-provider-package-similar/67880792#67880792)

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    var result = Provider.of<Home>(context).notification;
    if (result == "Play") {
      _controller.forward();
    }
  }
```

However, this is just a work-around and I am still looking to find a more efficient way to manage this (start/stop animation in a stateful widget from another unrelated widget, using Provider / or other solution).

Answer (score 0):

A `ValueNotifier<T>` from the `provider` package has the following properties:

- A `value` property of type `T`
- A `hasListeners` getter, inherited from `ChangeNotifier`
- A `dispose` method, inherited from `ChangeNotifier`
- A `notifyListeners` method, inherited from `ChangeNotifier`
- A `addListener` method, inherited from `Listenable`
- A `removeListener` method, inherited from `Listenable`

A `AnimationController` from the Flutter SDK has the following properties:

- A `value` property of type `bool`
- `didRegisterListener` and `didUnregisterListener` methods, inherited from `AnimationLocalListenersMixin`
- A `dispose` method, inherited from `AnimationLocalListenersMixin`
- A `notifyListeners` method, inherited from `AnimationLocalListenersMixin`
- A `addListener` method, inherited from `Listenable`
- A `removeListener` method, inherited from `Listenable`

---

Note that, except by `hasListeners` getter, an `AnimationController` can implement a `ValueNotifier<bool>`, which we can do as follows:

```dart
class AnimationControllerNotifier extends AnimationController
    implements ValueNotifier<double> {
  AnimationControllerNotifier({required super.vsync});

  int _listenersCount = 0;

  @override
  void didRegisterListener() {
    ++_listenersCount;
    super.didRegisterListener();
  }

  @override
  void didUnregisterListener() {
    --_listenersCount;
    super.didUnregisterListener();
  }

  @override
  bool get hasListeners => _listenersCount > 0;
}
```

Now we can use our `AnimationControllerNotifier` with the `provider` package:

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider<AnimationControllerNotifier>(
  create: (_) => AnimationControllerNotifier(vsync: /* ... */),
);
```